# Change SearchView backbutton in Android

Tags: android, button, searchview

I have Action bar in white color, When I click on search view button, I am able to get the search view but Unable to get the line beneath of search view and unable to see the back button. I want to change the color/complete icon of search view back button and I want to get the line beneath of search view. I Googled for it and tried lot of different ways, but no luck. I have tried changing the toolbar style also, but no luck. I am using search view in activities and Fragments too..

I have tried changing the toolbar style like below

```
 <style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:collapseIcon" tools:ignore="NewApi">@mipmap/filter_red</item>
</style>
```

Any help would be Grateful!!!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "I...tried lot of different ways" - You should include those attempts in the question, along with a description of how each failed, so there's no time wasted on unusable suggestions.

Comment: Done... Updated the code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(i) You can include `app:collapseIcon` attribute in your `Toolbar`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="2dp"
            app:collapseIcon="@drawable/cancel"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

(ii) Another way is to do that programmatically, with the help of AppBarLayout.

```
AppBarLayout appBar =  findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
        appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof ImageButton) {
                        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) view;
                        btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cancel)); // Here we can change icon.
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Layout will be as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!!!! Do I need to Include Toolbar In every layout???? I need to make it Global, Is there any way of doing like this????

Comment: Yeah.. You can do it programmatically,  with AppBarLayout. I will update the answer now.

Comment: Can you post your code, which worked for you.. I will compare your code with my code... Please try to post your xml and java code

Comment: Finally I found the Answer, I just Added the below piece of code in styles.xml  AppTheme      <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_back</item>                         can you say How can I get the bottom line for Search View

Comment: Cooll. You can add this line, **searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha);**  to get bottom line.

Comment: Is it possible to change bottom line from styles.xml, because I have search view in lot of classes